# Angular2: Setting and maintaining a CSS class when clicking on an element

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I am currently working on an Angular 2 webapp. In a view, the active element should get an additional CSS class when clicked. The element that is clicked, needs to get an additional CSS class.Adding the CSS attribute ":active" including an own CSS class is not working, because the class is removed when the user removes the finger from the mouse button. The CSS property ":focus" is not working at all. I tried with Angular2 directives Ng-click, ng-switch, ng-if and ng-class. 
The code so far -

The template:

```
<footer>
<div class="thumbnail-slider">
    <div class="thumbnail-img-container">
        <img class="thumbnail-slider-img" (click)="getActualImage(url)" 
            *ngFor="let url of urls" [src]="url"/>
    </div>
</div>
</footer>
```

The component:

```
    import { Component, NgModule, Input, Output, ViewChild, EventEmitter, ElementRef, OnInit, AfterViewInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
    import { BrowserModule, DomSanitizer, SafeUrl } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import { Http, Response, ResponseContentType } from '@angular/http';

 ReqConstImages } from '../../services';
    import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';
    import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
    import { ObservableUtility } from '../../helper/index';
    import { trigger, state, style, transition, animate } from '@angular/animations';


    let css: any = require('!raw-loader!less-loader!./thumbnail-slider.less');

    @Component({
      selector: 'thumbnail-slider',
      templateUrl: 'thumbnail-slider.html',
      styleUrls: [css],
      animations: [
      trigger('click', [
        state('inactive', style({
          border: '5px yellow solid'
        })),
        state('active',   style({
          border: '6px green solid'
        }))
      ])
    ]

    })

    export class ThumbnailSliderComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {


      constructor(private http: Http, private sanitizer: DomSanitizer, private observableUtility: ObservableUtility) { };




    }
```

This doesn´t seem to be a big deal; however, I haven´t figured out the right solution yet. The element that is clicked just needs an additional CSS class. As I am new to Angular2, any hints or help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: you can try `[class.active]="isActive" [class.inactive]="!isActive"` and toggle the isActive in the function. Also move the CSS classes to component's style. or give a default css and use either active or inactive as an override.

Comment: also the question is no very clear... how many elements you want to apply the new class. ?  is it one time, say once you click the element, the class is applied, and it should stay applied for every. ? which exact element in the HTML you have provided are you targeting?

Comment: @redflar3: Just for one element - thumbnail-slider-img - the css class should stay applied until the user clicks on another image in the thumbnail slider. Basically, it is a thumbnail slider where the active image is selected. It should stay applied. Does that answer your questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like below. use a variable `selectedUrl` to store the clicked URL, check if it matched the iterating image, and if so, set the class `active`.

```
  <img 
       class="thumbnail-slider-img" 
       *ngFor="let url of urls"
       [src]="url"
       (click)="selectedUrl=url"
       [class.active]="selectedUrl === url"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try creating a new variable in your component ts, change the value in the clicked function and finally use inside of the class attribute

like:
*.ts

```
public changedClass = "class1";

onClickedItem(){
    this.changedClass = "class2";
}
```

*.html (Template)

```
<div class="{{changedClass}}" (click)="onClickedItem()"></div>
```

here you have a code to change the class in the element when you click it.